# How to get rid of Atom's Welcome screen

Tags: atom-editor

[image]
I searched around the net and the solutions are too complicated. Is there any easy way to get rid of the "Welcome Guide" Screen?

Comment: Related issue for searchers who arrive here: To disable Telemetry Consent tab, do Settings->Packages->Metrics->Disable.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

You have two solutions. I think the second achieves the best when you say "to get rid of":

1. By unchecking the option `Show On Startup` in the configuration of the `Welcome` plugin (`Settings` » `Packages` » `welcome`), `Atom` doesn't show the `Welcome` screen at startup (or when opening a new `Atom` window), but still loads the plugin:

[image: Atom Welcome Plug-in 'Show On Startup' Setting]

2. By disabling the `Welcome` plugin (`Settings` » `Packages` » `welcome`), `Atom` doesn't load it (which saves memory) and so doesn't show the `Welcome` screen (under any circumstance):

[image: Atom Welcome Plug-in Info Panel]]

Answer (score 4):

On OS X, you go to menu *Atom* → *Preferences* → *Packages* and then you have to either find *Welcome in the Core Packages* or use the filter. You can't get there by going directly to `packages` in the top nav. Crazy.

Answer (score 4):

I am running Linux Mint and I deselected to "show on startup" and turned off telemetry, but for some reason was never saved and always showed. Even going through preferences did nothing for me to fix the issue. This was the only thing that fixed it for me was creating a config file for it in my home directory under the `.atom` directory.

`cat ~/.atom/config.cson 
"*":
  core:
    telemetryConsent: "no"
  welcome:
    showOnStartup: false`

There are other values for this file, but these should turn off the `Welcome screen` and `Telemetry` if it keeps showing up for you.

Comment: This proved to be the best option for me. Per another answer, the check-mark on the Welcome screen to disable it on did not appear in the v1.60.0 version I was running. And editing the `.cson` file was the most straightforward was to disable it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds pretty trivial, but after disabling the welcome guide from the welcome page,

[image]

and restarting Atom you may still see the welcome guide if you didn't close the page and have the "Restore Previous Windows On Start" (under *Settings* → *Core*) set to "yes" or "always":

[image]

Simply make sure to close the welcome guide before you restart Atom (or if you do not want to have windows restored you can also change that option to "no").

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way that worked for me is when the welcome page appears, uncheck the `Show welcome guide when open`. For clarification [Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20FeA.png)

Comment: Think that didn't exist when the question was asked. But if there's such a checkmark then it's the right answer.

Comment: I can confirm I did not see that checkbox in Atom version `1.60.0 x64` but I suspect that means I need to update Atom. When I try to check for updates in the 'Atom -> Check for Updates' menu option it returns an error. At the time of this comment, latest Atom version is 1.63.1